# Xamarin Android: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, permissions, google-vision

I have a Xamarin.Forms Android app where the page in question looks like this:

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="30,24,30,24" Spacing="10">
            <Image x:Name="CapturedImage" Source="{Binding Capture}" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100"/>
            <Button Margin="0,10,0,0" Text="Capture photo"
                    Command="{Binding OpenCameraCommand}"
                    BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
                    TextColor="White" />
            <Label Text="{Binding Description}" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</Grid>
```

With the button I open the Android native camera, which works. In the ViewModel the following happens:

```
public class CaptureViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private string _description;
    public string Description
    {
        get => _description;
        set
        {
            _description = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        } 
    }

    private ImageSource _capture;
    public ImageSource Capture
    {
        get => _capture;
        set
        {
            _capture = value;
            Description = value.ToString();
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ICommand OpenCameraCommand { get; }
    
    public CaptureViewModel()
    {
        Title = "Capture";
        OpenCameraCommand = new Command(OnExecute);
    }

    private async void OnExecute()
    {
        await TakePhotoAsync();
    }

    private async Task TakePhotoAsync()
    {
        var mpo = new MediaPickerOptions
        {
            Title = "test"
        };

        var photo = await MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync(mpo);

        await LoadPhotoAsync(photo);

        var image = await Image.FromFileAsync(Capture.ToString());

        var client = await ImageAnnotatorClient.CreateAsync();
        var textAnnotations = await client.DetectTextAsync(image);
        foreach (var text in textAnnotations)
        {
            Description = text.Description;
        }

    }

    private async Task LoadPhotoAsync(FileResult photo)
    {
        if (photo == null)
        {
            Capture = null;
            return;
        }
        var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        var newFile = Path.Combine(path, photo.FileName);

        using (var stream = await photo.OpenReadAsync())
        {
            var newStream = File.OpenWrite(newFile);
            await stream.CopyToAsync(newStream);

            newStream.Close();
            newStream.Dispose();
        }

        Capture = newFile;
    }
}
```

I actually want to use the ImageAnnotator seen in the VM, but I always get an error when trying to getting the captured image for processing.

[could not find path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVgCx.png)

> **System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException:** 'Could not find a part of the path "/File: /data/user/0/com.companyname.app2/files/df033720bb9646928a9626e25e116990.jpg".'

My permissions in AndroidManifest.xml look like:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="30" />
<application android:label="App2.Android" android:theme="@style/MainTheme"></application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I don't know what else could be wrong, but I tried a few other things, that didn't help. What might be the problem?

EDIT: I can see the Capture in the view, btw. and the Label for debugging reasons also shows a path (the same as in the pic).

Comment: which **specific** line is causing the exception?  You appear to be using a file url, not a path

Comment: It crashes at this line:

`var image = await Image.FromFileAsync(Capture.ToString());`

I am not sure, if it just shows the **File:** in the Debugger.

Comment: `Capture` is an `ImageSource`, why would you possibly think `Capture.ToString()` would return a file path?  Why aren't you using `photo` to get the path?

Comment: Oh, you are completely right! I made it extremely complicated and dumb. Turns out photo has FullPath and that just works :) Thank you Jason, I am new to Xamarin!

Comment: I am curious: what was the value of `FullPath`? It was a different directory? BTW, you can add "Your Answer" below, with the details of what worked. (Some people might not read through the comments here.) This will help others in the future. Thanks!

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve FuulPath returned `/data/user/0/com.companyname.app2/cache/2203693cc04e0be7f4f024d5f9499e13/6e02a0d384b144d6bbe0f6d5d6b961df/654e035499b8467a9d4293daf82d77e9.jpg`. Will add the details soon.

Answer (score 1):

So the solution here was to use the `FullPath`property from the returned `FileResult` to get the correct path needed to turn it into a stream.

wrong:

```
var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
    var newFile = Path.Combine(path, photo.FileName);
```

right:

```
var photo = await MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync(mpo);
var photoFullPath = photo.FullPath;

Capture = photoFullPath;

var image = await Image.FromFileAsync(photoFullPath);
```